# Bypass Transparent Squid With IPTables

Tags: iptables, squid

Similar questions have been asked before but the answers received were not satisfying or didn't apply to my situation.

I have a transparent squid proxy that filters all the http and , for some machines only, https traffic of my network.I achieved this with the following iptables rules:

```
  iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
    iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -s 192.168.1.100 -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3127
    iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -s 192.168.1.101 -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3127
    iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -s 192.168.1.102 -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3127
```

I would like however to bypass squid for certain domains:
when a client makes a request to mydomain.com it should directly go to the network's gateway.

I tried inserting the following rules BEFORE the others, mentioned above.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -d $IP_OF_MYDOMAIN.COM -j DNAT --to-destination $IP_OF_ROUTER
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -s $IP_OF_ROUTER -j RETURN
```

This setup however is not working. What am I missing? Is there a better way of doing this?

**edit**

The order of the rules is the following:

```
        iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -d $IP_OF_MYDOMAIN.COM -j DNAT --to-destination $IP_OF_ROUTER
        iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -s $IP_OF_ROUTER -j RETURN
        iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
        iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -s 192.168.1.100 -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3127
        iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -s 192.168.1.101 -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3127
        iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -s 192.168.1.102 -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3127
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to exempt traffic to a certain IP address from forcible redirection.  Is so, you're going about it the wrong way.

Replace the first two lines in the `iptables` config above with

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d a.b.c.d -j ACCEPT
```

where `a.b.c.d` is the ip address to be exempted from compulsory redirection.  Note that like your current pair of rules, this rule will need to come **before** the compulsory redirection code.